# Passing URL parameters to a Drupal form created in a menu item

Tags: forms, drupal, drupal-7

I am using Drupal 7 and have a custom module where I am creating a menu item which will display a Drupal form. The code is setup like this:

```
$items['job-seekers/update-resume/%'] = array(
  'title' => 'Update Resume',
  'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
  'page arguments' => 'oa_onboard_update_resume_form',    
  'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  'page arguments' => array(2),
);
```

So my menu item will display a form, but I need to take the parameter passed in the URL and have it stored in a hidden form field that will end up getting passed to the form submission method for processing. My form code looks like this:

```
/**
 * Form callback for updating resume
 */
function oa_onboard_update_resume_form($form_state) {  

  $form['resume_file'] = array(
    '#type' => 'file',
    '#title' => t('Resume Upload'),
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit'),
  );

  return $form;
}
```

So it's a very simple form that is just a file upload field, however I can't figure out how to gain access to the ID that is passed in the URL. Originally I was thinking I needed to account for it in the form method like so:

```
function oa_onboard_update_resume_form($candidateId) {
```

But I get an error when I try to do that:

```
Notice: Undefined index: 20249278 in drupal_retrieve_form() (line 763 of C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\includes\form.inc).
Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function '20249278' not found or invalid function name in drupal_retrieve_form() (line 798 of C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\includes\form.inc).
```

I think I might be going about this the wrong way. The bottom line is I just need to create a URL that I can pass an ID to that will display a form and pass that ID to the submit method along with the file upload.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
Here is the new callback function that renders the form after fixing the menu item per the suggestion below:

```
function oa_onboard_update_resume_form($candidateId) {  

  $form['candidateId'] = array(
    '#type' => 'hidden',
    '#value' => $candidateId,
  );

  $form['resume_file'] = array(
    '#type' => 'file',
    '#title' => t('Resume Upload'),
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit'),
  );

  return $form;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so this is what ended up working:

```
$items['job-seekers/update-resume/%'] = array(
  'title' => 'Update Resume',
  'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
  'page arguments' => array('oa_onboard_update_resume_form', 2),
  'access arguments' => array('access content'),
);

function oa_onboard_update_resume_form($form, &$form_state, $candidateId) {
  // I can use candidateId here now
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the hook_menu function you have twice set *'page arguments'* and you should use the *'page callback'* with the function `oa_onboard_update_resume_form`.

```
$items['job-seekers/update-resume/%'] = array(
  'title' => 'Update Resume',
  'page callback' => 'oa_onboard_update_resume_form',    
  'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  'page arguments' => array(2),
);
```

Comment: Wow I can't believe I didn't see that. OK so now I am having a different issue. Actually two. So I fixed the code in the menu link, but for some reason the value that I pass in the URL is getting cut off. In other words if I go to /job-seekers/update-resume/2058569, my hidden form field only contains "2". Also my form submit button does nothing. The form renders and I can choose a file to upload, but clicking the submit button does not submit the form. I updated my original post to show you what I am using as my callback function to render the form.

Comment: You can give some upvote to my answer if you like. I 've spend some time to solve the initial problem.